# CodeIgniter + MongoDB Update

Tags: php, codeigniter, mongodb, activerecord

I'm trying to use the library [codeigniter-library-mongodb](https://github.com/alexbilbie/codeigniter-mongodb-library) nested in a collection. But I am not able to do updates ...

To query I am using the following code:

```
getFacebookUser function ($ id ='') {
   return $ this-> mongo_db-> get_where ('users', array ('facebook.id' => $ id));
}
```

To insert:

```
createFacebookUser function ($ id ='', $ acess_token ='') {
   $user = array (
     'facebook' => array (
       'id' => $ id,
       'acess_token' => $ acess_token
     )
   );
   $ this-> mongo_db-> insert ('users', $ user);
}
```

I tried using the following code:

```
updateFacebookUser function ($ id ='', $ acess_token ='') {
    $ this-> mongo_db-> update ('users', array ('facebook.acess_token' => $ acess_token), array ('facebook.id' => $ id));
}
```

But I am getting the following message:

Nothing to update in Mongo collection or update is not an array

The structure I'm using is the following:

```
user {
     name,
     {facebook
         id,
         acess_token
     }
     {twitter
        id,
        acess_token
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be a typo, but it seems that you are trying to update the 'users' collection when your schema says it is called 'user'.